# Ignore specific rules in specific directory with Ruff

Tags: python, ruff

I am using [Ruff](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/), a formatter or linter tool for Python code.

I want to ignore some specific rules, and to write that config in `pyproject.toml`.

My package structure is as follows.

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── mypackage/mymodule.py
└── tests
    ├── doc.md
    └── test_mymodule.py
```

And, I want to ignore rules [pydocstyle (D)](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/#pydocstyle-d) in the `tests/` directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Ruff's `per-file-ignores` and specify individual files, or select a directory tree with a wildcard (star). You can ignore a "letter class" by specifying only the letter.

#### Example: Ignore specific rule in a specific file

To ignore line-length violations in your tests, add this to pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.ruff.lint.per-file-ignores]
"foofile.py" = ["E501"]
```

#### Example: Ignore a class of rules in a whole directory tree

To ignore all pydocstyle errors (starting with "D") in your tests, add this to pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.ruff.lint.per-file-ignores]
"tests/*" = ["D"]
```

The related Ruff docs are [here](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/configuration/).

Comment: If anyone else has the issue where Ruff complains `lint` wasn't an expected property for `tool.ruff`, ensure Ruff is up-to-date.